# Bootstrap Datepicker - Set startDate with multidate

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I have a datepicker div with multi date and a few dates set with setDates.

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  multidate: true,
  startDate: "08/01/2016",
  endDate: "11/30/2016"
});

$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDates',["08/01/2016","09/10/2016","10/15/2016","11/30/2016"]);
```

The problem is that it shows the last date by default(11/30/2016). I want it showing the first date instead(08/01/2016). What should I do?

The JSFiddle is: https://jsfiddle.net/itzuki87/tdj2Lscr/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just switch 1st date with last date:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
  multidate: true,
  startDate: "08/01/2016",
  endDate: "11/30/2016"
});

$("#datepicker").datepicker('setDates',["11/30/2016","09/10/2016","10/15/2016","08/01/2016"]);
```